# Cant send Object with property that has array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, node.js

I'm trying to send an object that looks like this

```
var postBody = {
        id: userID,
        objectID: [0, 1],
        objects: [
            {id: 0, x: 0.33930041152263374, y: 0.08145246913580247, width: 0.0823045267489712, height: 0.30864197530864196},
            {id: 1, x: 0.5277777777777778, y: 0.08453888888888889, width: 0.0823045267489712, height: 0.30864197530864196}
        ]
    };
```

this is ajax call

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: postBody,
        dataType: 'JSONP',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

this is what it looks like on server

```
 { id: '583f137fc338b517ec467643',
'objectID[]': [ '0', '1' ],
'objects[0][id]': '0',
'objects[0][x]': '0.33930041152263374',
'objects[0][y]': '0.08145246913580247',
'objects[0][width]': '0.0823045267489712',
'objects[0][height]': '0.30864197530864196',
'objects[1][id]': '1',
'objects[1][x]': '0.5277777777777778',
'objects[1][y]': '0.08453888888888889',
'objects[1][width]': '0.0823045267489712',
'objects[1][height]': '0.30864197530864196' }
```

if I put data: JSON.stringify(postBody) this is what I get

```
{ '{"id":"583f137fc338b517ec467643","objectID":[0,1],"objects":[{"id":0,"x":0.5,"y":0.5,"width":0.1,"height":0.1},{"id":1,"x":0.5401234567901234,"y":0.1833043209876543,"width":0.0823045267489712,"height":0.30864197530864196}]}': '' }
```

And it works! but then I cannot JSON.parse() it
this is what I get when I try

```
TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
```

and all that Im doing on data on backend is this

```
console.log(JSON.parse(req.body)); // in the first example it was the same thing but only without JSON.parse()
```

Anyone have an idea why this is happening here?
Even if you have a suggestion on what I could try feel free to post here, otherwise I'm gonna have to write a function for parsing these badass inputs lol.

Comment: I think the response you're trying to `JSON.parse` is already a json object being returned by the server. Can you post the response from the sever?

Comment: @Lex - I think you're right, depending on op's server setup - the response is already an `object`

Answer (score 1):

All the parsing/stringifying is handled by Node, so don't worry about it, just pass your object as it is, and you'll be able to access its properties in req.body.

client :

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: postBody,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
```

server :

```
 console.log(req.body);  //should give you [Object object]
```

you can then send it right back with: `res.status(200).json(req.body));`

and read it in your ajax callback :

```
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
},
```